# Selecting updated rows between two tables

Tags: sql

Good day,

I have to identical table structures. One is base table and second has incremental changes. I wish to have resulting table so that I pick he rows from the update, if present. Otherwise from old table.

Like so

```
table a: | Table b: | Result table: 
key val  |  key val | key val 
1   a    |  2   bb  |  1   a   
2   b    |  4   dd  |  2   bb
3   c    |  5   ee  |  3   c
4   d    |          |  4   dd
                       5   ee
```

I tried selecting B table values on **inner join** and **full outer join where a.key is NULL or b.key is NULL** and **union**. (Code not tested to functionality yet.)

```
select * from 
(
  (select table_B.* from 
    TABLE_A
      inner join 
    TABLE_B
    on TABLE_A.key = TABLE_B.key 
  )
  UNION 
  (select * from 
    TABLE_A
     full outer join
    TABLE_B
  on TABLE_A.key = TABLE_B.key 
  where TABLE_A.key is NULL or TABLE_A.key is NULL
  )
)
```

Is there an easier way to do this? I got the feeling that there has to be a more robust way to do this.

**EDIT:** I'm currently implementing this in the SPARK SQL context, but have had similar issues in the SQL server environment. Yet, I'm looking for a general idea.

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: Why do you want d and not dd for key 4? (d is fine, but dd is even better...)

Comment: @jarth is right. Why do you want `d` instead of `dd`? [LOL]

Comment: @TheImpaler, why is your answer deleted. Close to perfect.

Comment: @jarlh Because of your comment. My answer would show `dd`.

Comment: @TheImpaler, OP wants dd now!

Comment: @jarlh Undeleted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding this would help

```
select key, val from Tableb
union
select key, val from Tablea a 
where not exists(select 1 from Tableb where a.key = b.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which database you are using, so I'll assume it implements `FULL OUTER JOIN`. You can do:

```
select
  coalesce(a.key, b.key),
  case when b.key is not null then b.val else a.val end
from a
full outer join b on a.key = b.key
order by coalesce(a.key, b.key)
```

Comment: This works with my example. However, I forgot to mention that there are other columns as well. More general solution gets my vote. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

One method is `full join`:

```
select key, coalesce(i.value, m.value) as value
from master m full join
     incremental i
     using (key);
```